# How to display value from an array in a Material Table Angular

Tags: angular

I'm working on a practice angular/spring boot application. I was able to retrieve data from the backend (which is a list of all users) and display it in the front end using angular material table but I am stuck on displaying the roles for that users which is an array since users can have multiple roles. I saw some example of using `*ngFor` but couldn't find any examples of it using material.

This is what I have so far

ts file

```
export class BoardUserComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: user[] = [];
  columnsToDisplay = ['id', "firstName", "lastName" ,"username", "email", "roles", "action"];
  
  constructor(private userService: UserService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(res => {
      this.dataSource = res;
      console.log(this.dataSource);
    });
  }
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #mytable class="my-table mat-elevation-z8">
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.firstName}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.lastName}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.username}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.email}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="roles">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Roles</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.roles}}</td> <!-- DISPLAYS   [object Object]-->
    </ng-container>

    <!-- ACTION COLUMN-->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Action</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="action-link"> 
        <button class="edit_deleteBtn" (click)="openDialog('Update',element)"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button> |
        <button class="edit_deleteBtn" (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm able to display the ID, FirstName, LastName, Username, and Email just fine. I'm having trouble displays the Roles.Name
sample of what the data looks like from the console

```
email: "mod@bez.com"
firstName: "John"
id: 1
lastName: "Doe"
roles: Array(2)
0:
id: 1
name: "ROLE_USER"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
id: 2
name: "ROLE_MODERATOR"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
username: "mod"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Not sure if it's the correct way but was able to display what I wanted. I basically did some manipulation after getting the data for the `User` info and added a new field in the `User` interface where I set the `roleName` as a string instead of an array. Also created a new interface of Roles which has the ID and the `roleName` variables and used that to temporarily store the values from the user info.

```
public getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(res => {
      this.dataSource = res;
      console.log(this.dataSource);
      
      let updatedRoleName;

      this.dataSource.forEach(user => {
        
        user.roles.forEach(role => {
          updatedRoleName = role.roleName;
        });

        user.roleName = updatedRoleName;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a familiar thing in my company website but it's made for dynamic tables.
In your case try like this

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="roles">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Roles</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <your-comp-selector [roles]="element"></your-comp-selector>
  </td> 
</ng-container>
```

So create a component that can have a button once pressed, display a modal with list or how ever you like it

> ng g c < your-row-array-name >

Then on your new comp, use

```
@Input() roles: Array<any>:
```

Following display on html

Comment: What if I don't want the user to click on a button to display all the roles. Right now, once the user goes to the page, it displays a table and under the role column, I just wanted to display like ROLE_MODERATOR